Attaching into an x86 process in windbg
How can I attach into an x86 process from windbg?
currently I am waiting for the process to load then I am breaking into wow64cpu!KiFastSystemCall to switch into x86 context and only then put bp to the instruction of interest, the problem is by the time I am doing it the instruction has already been executed.
Other approached like sxe just doesn't work, is it because its x86 process or am I doing something wrong?
I would appreciate a detailed answer about how to do it.

use x86 version of windbg for x86 applications then you don't have to deal with wow also attaching means you are dealing with a running process so initialisation code would have been executed  try creating the process like windbg foo.exe to debug from beginning if that is what you mean in your query

Are you debugging the process from a kernel debugger? or just in a regular user-mode context?

kernel debugger

If you are able to run ntsd in the target you can use ntsd -d to redirect your app to the kernel debugger. Search ntsd -d  in stack overflow under my nick like user:xxxcc ntsd -d you should hit several posts explaining how to do it

Try this, the code is in here.
It basically puts a breakpoint on nt!NtCreateUserProcess and parses the args to check if the process name is the wanted target process.
And in case of the finding the target process it switches to the process context by using .process /i <eprocess_address> and then continuing the execution with g to break in the target process context.
Credits to my co-worker Shaked Reiner :)
